# Natural Filtration and Sigma-Field Generated by path function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a continuous real-valued stochastic process $X=(X_t;t\geq 0)$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$. Usually one defined the filtration to be $F_t=\sigma(X_s;s\leq t)$.

But on the other hand, one can also consider the random element $X^{t}:\Omega\rightarrow C[0,t]$ defined by $(X^t(\omega))(s)=X(s,\omega)$, where $C[0,t]$ is the space of continuous functions on $[0,t]$ (equipped with Borel sigma-algebra). So another choice for filtration could be the sigma-algebra $\tilde{F}_t$ generated by $X^t$.

I am just wondering are $F_t$ and $\tilde{F}_t$ different? Which is larger?

Comment: If you have a borel sigma field you should precise the topology associated with it. I know that in Karatzas and Shreve's book on Brownian motion and stochastic calculus there is an exercise that allow to show if I remember well that both are equivalent for the sup over compact topology, I don't know the answer for the general problem but it might be possible to elaborate further from this example. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge The topology is just the one generated by the uniform norm on C[0,t].

Comment: @TheBridge So it sounds like the exercise is the same as my question here. Could you find which page the exercise is on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as suggested by @TheBridge, I found that problem 4.2 on page 60 of Karatzas and Shreve's *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* (2nd edition) demonstrates my question. The answer is positive. To be more succinct, the Borel sigma-algebra on $C[0,t]$ is the same as the product sigma-algebra $\mathbb{R}^{[0,t]}$ (i.e., the smallest sigma-algebra such that every coordinate map is measurable).

Example 1.3 on page 11 of Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures* (2nd edition) also has this result.